# How to Skip Flutter iOS Build

Tags: xcode, flutter, build

I don't really use the iPhone simulator, so I deleted Xcode. After deleting Xcode, when I try to run the app I get an error:

```
[chat_app] flutter pub get
xcrun: error: active developer path ("/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer") does not exist
Use `sudo xcode-select --switch path/to/Xcode.app` to specify the Xcode that you wish to use for command line developer tools, or use `xcode-select --install` to install the standalone command line developer tools.
See `man xcode-select` for more details.
Running "flutter pub get" in chat_app...                        
The current Flutter SDK version is 0.0.0-unknown.



Because chat_app depends on firebase_auth >=0.5.0 which requires Flutter SDK version >=0.1.4, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; Because chat_app depends on firebase_auth >=0.5.0 which requires Flutter SDK version >=0.1.4, version solving failed.)
exit code 1
```

Is there a way to tell Flutter to skip the iOS build and only build for Android?

Answer (score 1):

When You Create The Project You can Tell Flutter to Create Project For Specific Platforms  using --Platform option,
if You did'nt do so ,then you have to select emulator as a target Device to build , and it will not build for IOS by default,